# How to define Z dimension on table with PostGIS for import in TileMill?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, carto, tilemill

I'm trying to reproduce the idea behind [this blogpost from Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/tilemill-complex-3d-structures/), but with other data, for example the `ne_10m_populated_places_simple` dataset from [Natural Earth](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector).  By adding a z-dimension to the data (eg. the `scalerank` column, size of city), the idea is to be able to set a height in `CartoCSS` in `Tilemil`l and get a 3D-representation of the data, with x,y as geo-point and z as value (like in Mapbox's example).

The result could perhaps be something like this (except this map is oblique, different story):

[image]

What do I need to do with `PostGIS` (or other) so that the z-dimension is set for value and correctly converted so I can set the `height` in `CartoCSS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to add a z-dimension in order to achieve the building-height that they use in that blog post. In fact, the map pluto image you posted is using the same cartocss method. Basically, you just need a column in your dataset that includes some variable for building-height. In their case, they have three columns, z_small, z_large, and z_xlarge, each of which is a numeric value.

Here, I've taken the style in the blog post and applied it in CartoDB,

[image: Imgur]

Here you can see I have columns for each of those (plus another column for the building size_sqm),

[image: Imgur]

### Answer to do it anyway

In case anyone comes across this thread and really really wants to get geometries with a z-dimension out of CartoDB, here is the way.

**Get default geometry**

```
SELECT the_geom FROM ne_50m_admin_1_states LIMIT 1
```

[and GeoJSON over the api](https://andrew.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=geojson&q=SELECT%20the_geom%20FROM%20ne_50m_admin_1_states%20LIMIT%201)

**Add Z of 100 to Geometry**

```
SELECT 
  ST_Translate(ST_Force3D(the_geom),0,0,100) AS the_geom 
FROM ne_50m_admin_1_states 
LIMIT 1
```

and GeoJSON over the API -

https://andrew.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=geojson&q=SELECT%20ST_Translate(ST_Force3D(the_geom),0,0,100)%20AS%20the_geom%20FROM%20ne_50m_admin_1_states%20LIMIT%201

**Add Z based on a second column**

In this case, I'll just use `cartodb_id` of each row to be the Z for the resulting geometry.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Translate(ST_Force3D(the_geom),0,0,cartodb_id) AS the_geom 
FROM ne_50m_admin_1_states 
LIMIT 1
```

and GeoJSON over the API -

https://andrew.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=geojson&q=SELECT%20ST_Translate(ST_Force3D(the_geom),0,0,cartodb_id)%20AS%20the_geom%20FROM%20ne_50m_admin_1_states%20LIMIT%201

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thanks.